# Event tracker does not track event in Google Analytics V4 in Android

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I have integrated Google Analytics V4 in my Android application. It tracks screen in real time but it does not track Events in my application. Am I missing some codes ?

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static final String TAG = MyApplication.class.getSimpleName();
    private static MyApplication mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mInstance = this;

        AnalyticsTrackers.initialize(this);
        AnalyticsTrackers.getInstance().get(com.jollyfoodfellow.customclass.AnalyticsTrackers.Target.APP);

    }

    public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public synchronized Tracker getGoogleAnalyticsTracker() {

        AnalyticsTrackers analyticsTracker = AnalyticsTrackers.getInstance();
        return analyticsTracker.get(com.jollyfoodfellow.customclass.AnalyticsTrackers.Target.APP);

    }

    public void trackEvent(String category, String action, String label) {
        Log.v(TAG, "##### Track Event is called ######");
        Tracker t = getGoogleAnalyticsTracker();
        t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder().setCategory(category).setAction(action).setLabel(label).build());

    }
}
```

AnalyticsTracker.java

```
public class AnalyticsTrackers {

    public enum Target {
        APP,
        // Add more trackers here if you need, and update the code in
        // #get(Target) below
    }

    private static AnalyticsTrackers sInstance;

    public static synchronized void initialize(Context context) {
        if (sInstance != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Extra call to initialize analytics trackers");
        }
        sInstance = new AnalyticsTrackers(context);
    }

    public static synchronized AnalyticsTrackers getInstance() {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Call initialize() before getInstance()");
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    private final Map<Target, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<Target, Tracker>();
    private final Context mContext;

    /**
     * Don't instantiate directly - use {@link #getInstance()} instead.
     */
    private AnalyticsTrackers(Context context) {
        mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    public synchronized Tracker get(Target target) {
        if (!mTrackers.containsKey(target)) {
            Tracker tracker;
            switch (target) {
            case APP:
                tracker = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(mContext).newTracker(R.xml.app_tracker);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unhandled analytics target " + target);
            }
            mTrackers.put(target, tracker);
        }

        return mTrackers.get(target);
    }

}
```

app_tracker.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- End current session if app sleeps for a period of time -->
    <integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">300</integer>

    <!-- Enable automatic Activity measurement -->
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

    <!-- The property id associated with this analytics tracker -->
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-XXXXXXX-X</string>
    <string name="ga_sampleFrequency">100.0</string>

    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
</resource>
```

and here is the click event code

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    MyApplication.getInstance().trackEvent(TAG, "Login Clicked", "User clicked on Login button");
}
```

Comment: Make sure you are giving enough time for the data to be processed. It takes up to 24 hours you can seeing something.

Comment: As far as i know, Event and Screen data normally take 1-2 minutes. Though, Exception and Crash reports take upto 24 hours to proceed data on dashboard @nyuen